# Security concerns writing php to file

Tags: php, file, security, eval

I'm creating code that allows me to create a libary of templates from the backend of my CMS website.  I create them in a textarea and then write them to a database.

I then get a text string from a database and then save it to a file people.php.

```
            $text='<?php echo\'<div class="tileContainer three_across_homePage">
              <div class="tileBox three_across_box_0_homePage">
                <div class="tileModule three_across_module_0_homePage">
                <a href="\'.$holder[0].\'"><img src="\'.$holder[1].\'" alt="\'.$holder[2].\'" />
                  <div class="centeredHomePage">
                    \'.$holder[2].\'
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </a> </div>
                </div>
              </div>\';';

            $file = 'people.php';
            $current = file_get_contents($file);
            $current = $text;
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

I then include this file in subsequent code which creates and uses the $holder array to fill in the place holders $holder[0], $holder[1] etc

The text string is written to the database from the admin area of a CMS.

The other obvious way to do this would be eval but that would be a big security risk.

So I'm wondering if the security risk is still too big and I should just write php files that are stored on the server directly.  However the trouble with this approach is how to update multiple site that are using the templates.

thanks

Comment: The maintenance overhead really outshines the security woes here. Either prepulate the values and store as html, or use any trivial templating engine.

Comment: Allowing your PHP application to create PHP files in your web root is definitely a security risk. If you are creating templates -- presumably HTML and CSS, maybe some JS, then why must you create PHP files? What's wrong with writing HTML snippets and having your PHP code load that HTML and merge parameters into it?

Comment: I guess I could do placeholders and then change them out for the variables which would allow me to do a text file for the string.  I'll try that